# I want to write to a text file at the inputed caret position with PHP

Tags: php, fseek

I want to wite to a text file at the inputed text position using PHP. I tried using fseek to point the wite position to the inputed number, but it saves as an empty file instead.

```
<?php
$testData = "testdata";
$testPosition = 3;
$fileReference = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fseek($fileReference, $testPosition);
fwrite($fileReference, $testData);
fclose($fileReference);
?>
```

How would I get the script to wite to the text file at the specified position correctly?

Comment: I have attempted to answer your question. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Though, now its writing everything in a single line when I view the text file afterward. I'm guessing there's some kind of problem with the way the new-line characters are interpreted.

Comment: for a new line in PHP, i personally have a variable called `$nL` and it literally is just a new line
`$nL = '<ENTER KEY>';`

Comment: Is there a way, do you think, to translate a Javascript new-line to one readable by other devices and back again? I'm attempting to pass data to the PHP script via XMLHttpRequest to write to the file, but the new-line characters are killing me.

Comment: are you looking to change JS `\n` to a php new line? if you you can use `str_replace()` to change them to my `$nL` type of new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The w flag only allows for writing to a file. Try replacing the w flag with a `r+` flag. This will allow for read/write to a file without truncating the file. the read /write is needed to allows you to go search for your caret and write to where it is. for more information on the fopen function please see [php.net: fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

The `w` flag has this functionality:

> 'w'     Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

This could be why you're getting an empty file.

However, on my local server, this works fine. This makes me think your permissions may not be correct. For example, you might not have write permissions. Try and ensure that you have the correct permissions on this file.